# Applications of Vector Geometry

Tags: geometry, vectors

Current in maths, we are learning vector geometry. Specifically, we are trying to express lengths on a diagram ( eg. CE ) as vectors in terms of vectors that are already given. For example:

[image: Example Question]

But what is the direct use or application of this? It feels like I'm not finding anything useful while solving these problems.

Comment: For starters, the algebraic formalism underlying computer graphics; analyzing forces in elementary mechanics; crystallography; solid geometry.

Comment: Now, I'm trying to calculate volume of solid in some complex configuration. Volume can be easily parameterized, so I need to express coordinates $x,y,z$ in terms of used parameters. Vector algebra is useful tool for this task.